# Android best way to pass object to another activity

Tags: android

I'm now starting on android and i was wondering which is the best way to pass an object from an activity to another.

So far i have

- Seriliazable
- Parcelable
- and there's always the other option to just pass an ID and create the object again
  through the database

Which one should i user?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating an object of intent, you can take advantage of following two methods 
for passing objects between two activities.

[putParceble](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelable%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29)

[putSerializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29)

What you can do with this, is have your class implement either [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html).

Then you can pass around your custom classes across activities. I have found this very useful.

Here is a small snippet of code I am using

```
CustomListing currentListing = new CustomListing();
Intent i = new Intent();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable(Constants.CUSTOM_LISTING, currentListing);
i.putExtras(b);
i.setClass(this, SearchDetailsActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

And in newly started activity code will be something like this...

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
if(b!=null)
    mCurrentListing = b.getParcelable(Constants.CUSTOM_LISTING);
```

Also you  could be letting your custom class implement `Serializable` interface and then you can pass object instances in intent extra using `putExtra(Serializable..)` variant of the `Intent#putExtra()` method.

PSEUDO code:

```
//to pass :
   intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);  

// to retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```